# Django: How is <classname>_set attribute created in models.Model subclass?

Tags: python, django

In Django, I can have a model Question and a model Choice:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return choice_text
```

I can then do this:

```
>>>q = Question(question_text = 'How are you?', pub_date = timezone.now())
>>>q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

The `q.choice_set`, according to my understanding, accesses the set of `Choice` objects in our database which refer to `q` by their foreign key.

My question is: How is the `choice_set` attribute being created? I've never seen a attribute name taking the name of another class in lower case letters. How is this achieved?

EDIT: To clarify, I'm asking about how Django sets the name of the variable dynamically, not the variable contents.

Comment: You'll need to check how this is implemented in the Django codebase: https://github.com/django/django/blob/bfb746f983aa741afa3709794e70f1e0ab6040b5/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L164

Comment: Slightly unrelated but I find it useful to rename the _set property by setting a related_name in the definition. models.ForeignKey(related_name='choices') will let you do- q.choices.all() instead of q.choice_set.all()

Comment: Thank you Moses, I had a look. Also, I see that the `model._meta` attribute is being used in the implementation, so I tried finding the `model`-class, but wasn't successful in doing so. It's probably not even called `model` since `model` is just the argument name in this particular function. Could you tell me where to find it?

Comment: @Sandi: Django's codebase is hard to navigate if you aren't used to its level of abstraction. The `_meta` attribute is defined in `django.db.models.options.Options.contribute_to_class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is decided by `ForeignObjectRel.get_accessor_name`. The actual attribute is set via `setattr()` in `RelatedField.contribute_to_related_class`.

Essentially, this happens when you create an instance of `ForeignKey`:

```
attribute_name = YourModel._meta.model_name + '_set'
setattr(foreign_key, attribute_name, SomeDescriptorClass(foreign_key))
```